# Add multiple attributes to product from php

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, post-meta

I'm trying to update a WooCommerce product entry with data from an API, where the values from the API match taxonomy terms I've created in my WordPress site.

For most fields this works, but I have one attribute that can contain multiple terms. Using `update_post_meta` I'm adding these, imploded to a string seperated by `|`.

```
$meta[] = array(
    'key' => 'pa_aantal_spelers',
    'value' => implode($players, ' | '),
    'visible' => 1,
 );
```

When I view the product in the dashboard, the attribute looks good but the values aren't interpreted correctly on the front-end on the site. When I then save the product, with the piped string  as the attribute value, the value is set correctly.

Any advice on how I should be setting these multiple terms in the product attribute?

Thanks

Comment: Exchange places of ` | ` and `$players`. See [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) syntax.

Comment: From that same page: "implode() can, for historical reasons, accept its parameters in either order". The string I'm saving *looks* good, just not sure if this is the way to save something like this.

Comment: Are you sure `$players` is an array? How do you create it?